# my default.aspx.vb is unable to see another myclass.cs file in same folder !

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am trying to use myclass.cs from aspx.vb  but receive error "myclass not declared"  when I give command:

Imports myclass

any ideas how to make a reference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot mix C# and VB.NET code files in the same project.  You need to add a new C# class library project containing myclass.cs and then add a reference to this project from your VB project.

---

EDIT: Apparently I was mistaken.  You CAN actually mix VB and C# in a web project if you put the .cs files in the App_Code folder.  You learn something new every day :-)

Comment: Is this correct? We can have .cs and .vb in the same project. We have to make some changes in the web.config file.

Comment: I am trying to make reference but it asks for DLL/EXE.  Do I need to compile class library proj?

Comment: No!!! You just have to copy the .cs file to App_Code folder and the class will be automatically compiled. BTW what version are you using?

Comment: Use the "Project" tab in the "Add reference" dialog box.

Answer (score 1):

1. Ensure you declared your class **public**.
2. Put your C# class into the App_Code folder.

Answer (score 0):

Copy the .cs file to App_Code folder and you should be able to import it. You can read more about App_Code folder [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t990ks23.aspx).